# Creating new web application from WSP file

Tags: sharepoint-2010

A web application is installed on our sharepoint server. I have the WSP and dll files for the solution  but not the source code. I need to make some changes in the code of the webpages of that application so I have to create a new web application with exact same functionality from scratch so that I have full control. How can I use the WSP and DLL files to create a new solution.
I have imported the WSP package in vs2010 and decompiled the dll file to get code behinds of aspx pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a shot to tools that reflect on code. You will be able to generate a lot of code OOB using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). Give it a shot.